# Best way to connect a GCP VPN to multiple private VPCs across multiple projects?

Tags: vpn

I have several GCP projects. All of them have private VPCs. I'd like to create a single VPN that can apply to all of the VPCs/projects. Is this possible with Shared VPC? What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Created all networks and subnets on the host project and connect all service projects to host projects by individual VPNs or network peering if you want to communicate with internal ips